# GUI: Decoupled view and design patterns for RIA

Tags: user-interface, design-patterns, language-agnostic, architecture

I made some GUI desktop applications on my first years of development, but my experience and practice have changed, so now I'd like to retake this subject with better knowledge.

Most of my experience has been web since then.

I've been reading about [GUI Architectures](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html), and several related questions here on S.O.. I know I'm still not in the "architect" level of knowledge from Design patterns and such, as to start building a great GUI App from scratch

I'm trying to figure out how to design an app with a GUI, using good design practices for the architecture. I'm focusing on MVC architectures, with RIAs (Flex, Java FX, you choose), thinking of keeping the GUI as decoupled as possible from the domain. This has brought me some trouble...

I've been having a hard time relating an MVC architecture such as SpringMVC with a GUI, which could also implement its own MVC. Most of what I've read are high level concepts, but I can't seem to be able to translate this into code.

"Where do I create the view?", "How do you hook the controller with the model and the view?", etc. These are some of the questions I keep asking myself after some reading and studying.

I'm probably kind of lost, and quite entangled as to where to start, so any help is appreciated.

Are there any guides/tutorials/documentation you can recommend to start on this subject? I should probably start with the RIA/GUI basics, and then specialize on the technology I'll use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify which language you prefer, but here are some practical guides for Java:

- Java SE Application Design With MVC:

  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/mvc-136693.html
- Model-View-Controller (MVC) Structure

  http://leepoint.net/notes-java/GUI/structure/40mvc.html

Also, for specifically SpringMVC, here are some practical guides:

http://maestric.com/doc/java/spring

http://www.zabada.com/tutorials/spring-mvc-basics.php